# multidimensional arrays with multiple datatypes in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensional array that includes an integer element and a datetime element. I want to be able to sort on the datetime element and grab the integer elements according to the sorted datetime elements. Is there a way to do this with arrays in c#, or should I be using something more like a datatable?

Comment: multidimentional? how do you want to sort it?

Comment: I think Ben meant a array of 2 columns, DateTime and int, like Dictionary<DateTime, int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for keep interegs and DateTimes, use the generic System.Collections.**Dictionary<*DateTime, int*>**

for keep the order, use System.Collections.Specialized.**OrderedDictionary**. See example in MSDN([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)).

```
// Creates and initializes a OrderedDictionary.
OrderedDictionary myOrderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey1", "testValue1");
myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey2", "testValue2");
myOrderedDictionary.Add("keyToDelete", "valueToDelete");
myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey3", "testValue3");

ICollection keyCollection = myOrderedDictionary.Keys;
ICollection valueCollection = myOrderedDictionary.Values;

// Display the contents using the key and value collections
DisplayContents(keyCollection, valueCollection, myOrderedDictionary.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `DataTable` would be far more appropriate for the operations you require, as it provides built-in support for sorting by column and other table-like operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>` as an element type for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably define a custom type:

```
public class Entity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int[] Elements { get; set; }
}
```

and use Linq with `Entity[]`. Here's an example with sorting:

```
var entities = new[] 
{
    new Entity
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2009, 12, 10)
    },
    new Entity
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2009, 12, 11)
    },
    new Entity
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2009, 12, 9)
    }
};
Array.Sort(entities, (e1, e2) => e1.Date.CompareTo(e2.Date));
```

Comment: I think this is a reasonable and appropriate approach. While `DataTable`s and multidimensional arrays can sometimes be appropriate, they are not a general substitute for meaningful model classes.